# How do I override this class property?

Tags: ios, swift

```
struct SectionData {
    var items : [LiveCellObjectProtocol] 
    var title: String? = nil
    subscript(index: Int) -> LiveCellObjectProtocol {
        return items[index]
    }
}

extension SectionData{
    init(title: String? = nil){
        self.title = title
        self.items = []
    }
}

class LiveCellTableViewController: UIViewController  {

    var sections: [SectionData] = {
        return [SectionData(title: "aaa"), SectionData(title: "bbb"), SectionData(title: "ccc")]
    }()
}
```

How do I override `sections` if I subclass this? I'd like to change the titles.

This doesn't build.

```
class SomeChild: LiveCellTableViewController {
    override var sections: [SectionData] = {
        return [SectionData(title:  nil), SectionData(title: "Mutual"), SectionData(title: "Connections")]
    }()
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? Also, I'm not clear on why you have `()` after the `}`.

Comment: XCode won't build unless it adds it (It suggests it too)

Comment: @Uncommon Because `()` actually runs the block. If the assignment operator was left out (making the property a computed one) the `()` should be left out.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I think @TIMEX meant to do a computed property.

Comment: @Uncommon Yeah, I noticed your answer below.

Answer (score 1):

An `override` property cannot be a stored property. That's just the way Swift works (and this makes sense if you think about it). I list the possibilities in [my book](http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_class_properties_and_methods) as follows:

> - If the superclass property is writable (a stored property or a computed property with a setter), the subclass’s override may consist
>     of adding setter observers to this property.
> - Alternatively, the subclass’s override may be a computed property. In that case:
>
>   - If the superclass property is stored, the subclass’s computed
>       property override must have both a getter and a setter.
>   - If the superclass property is computed, the subclass’s computed
>       property override must reimplement all the accessors that the
>       superclass implements. If the superclass property is read-only (it has
>       just a getter), the override can add a setter.

So the way to do what you want to do here is to override, not the property, but the class's *initializer*. Here's a highly simplified example:

```
class C {
    var sections : [Int] = [1,2,3]
}

class CC : C {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        super.sections = [4,5,6]
    }
}

C().sections // [1,2,3]
CC().sections // [4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the equals signs:

```
var sections: [SectionData] {
  return [SectionData(title: "aaa"), SectionData(title: "bbb"), SectionData(title: "ccc")]
}
```

That's why Xcode wanted parentheses. With the equals sign, your code block was defining an inline function, and the `()` calls the function, using the result to initialize your variable. Without the `()` you're trying to assign a function to an array.

Without the `=`, you're defining a property with a getter, which (I assume) is what you want.

Comment: This does something very different than the original code, and different from the apparent intent as well.  The original creates a STORED property and initializes it with the return value of a block, so it can be changed later.  Yours creates a COMPUTED property which will always return the same value and can't be changed.

Comment: Exactly. It looks to me like a computed property is what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override a stored property in swift. You can use private storage and calculated properties to work around the issue. Something like this:

```
 //: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

struct SectionData {
    let title: String
}

class ParentClass {

    private let defaultSections = [SectionData(title: "Parent")]

    var sections: [SectionData] {
        return defaultSections
    }

}

class ChildClass: ParentClass {

    private let childSections = [SectionData(title: "Child")]

    override var sections: [SectionData] {
        return childSections
    }

}

// If you wanted a child who appends sections

class AnotherChildClass: ParentClass {

    private let childSections = [SectionData(title: "Child")]

    override var sections: [SectionData] {
        return super.sections + childSections
    }

}
```

Also, because in your example you're just overriding the parent class functionality and your property is immutable, you could just make it a parameter passed in during init.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

struct SectionData {
    let title: String
}

class ParentClass {

    let sections: [SectionData]

    init(sections: [SectionData]) {
        self.sections = sections
    }
}

class ChildClass: ParentClass {

}

let parent = ParentClass(sections: [SectionData(title: "Parent")])
let child = ChildClass(sections: [SectionData(title: "Child")])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the value in your subclass after you create it, if you're loading it from a storyboard, the easiest place is in `awakeFromNib`:

```
class SomeChild: LiveCellTableViewController {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        sections = [SectionData(title:  nil), SectionData(title: "Mutual"), SectionData(title: "Connections")]
    }
}
```